# How to access a required module from different files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In Node.js I'm using Socker.io in my main.js like this

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Also Im using a "sub"-file like api.js which I want to use to delecate some of my business logic away from the main. So I imported also this one like

```
const api = require('./api.js');
```

In my api.js how can I now use the socket.io framework? Can I access the instance from above from a different file? Or do I have to pass the "io"-object like this: `api.myFoo(io);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every place that you say `require('module')` you will get the same instance of that module.

But here when you want to share the return value of a function, then you have to export it explicitly:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
module.exports = io;
```

in some module, and require it in another modules by:

```
const io = require('./your-module');
```

Other option would be to pass it as an argument to other modules, like this:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const api = require('./api.js')(io);
```

but in that case your `api.js` would have to export a function that takes `io` as an argument:

```
module.exports = (io) => {
    return ... // return whatever was exported before
};
```

Comment: Good answer! Just the last part confuses me: Cant I just do something like this in api.js: exports.io = io; ?

Comment: @MarcM My last example is showing how the `api.js` can get the `io` value when it is called as `api = require('./api.js')(io);` in some other module that has the `io` and wants to pass it to the `api.js`. You can do `exports.io = io;` instead of `module.exports = io;` in my first example - when you have `io` and want to export it. It all depends on what is the direction of passing the `io` object - whether you pass it from the required module to the requiring module or the other way around.